# Is there a way to change the scope of a named range from workbook to worksheet using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, named-ranges

I created a named ranges on my Excel sheet using the function define_name()

```
 with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_broker, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        # Get xlsxwriter objects
        workbook = writer.book
        header = workbook.add_format({'bold':True, 'border' : 1 })
        format_float = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '# ###'})

        takerMaker_client.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Maker Taker", index_label = ["", "", ""], 
                                                        startrow=5)
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Maker Taker']
        worksheet.set_column('D:E', 20, format_float)
        workbook.define_name('Client', '=OFFSET(\'Maker Taker\'!$D$7,,,COUNTA(\'Maker Taker\'!$D$7:$D$1048576),)')
```

but when I try to create a chart on PowerPoint using the named range 'Client', I notice that it is linked to the name of my Excel File and not the name of my Excel sheet.

```
='ExcelFile_Name.xlsx'!Client
```

Is there a way to set the scope of my named range from 'Workbook' to 'Worksheet' on Python to get:

```
='Maker Taker'!Client
```

I tried the function worksheet.define_name instead of workbook.define_name but this function doesn't eist and there is no scope parameter in the function define_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `writer.book` does represent the whole file, but its actual type and associated methods can depend on the underlying engine. As you are using `workbook.define_name` which looks like the xlswriter method, I shall assume that your Pandas instance uses the xlswriter engine.

In that case, the [xlswriter documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#workbook-define-name) says:

> It is also possible to define a local/worksheet name by prefixing it with the sheet name using the syntax `'sheetname!definedname'`

So you should use:

```
workbook.define_name("'Maker Taker'!Client",
    "=OFFSET('Maker Taker'!$D$7,,,COUNTA('Maker Taker'!$D$7:$D$1048576),)")
```

Beware: untested...

Comment: Thank you Serge ! It worked perfectly when I added the sheet name